# How do i set a variable in a store procedure to a value in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

im trying to create a stored procedure for my booking application that checks a status of a current holiday and from that then decides what to change the status to after a stored procedure is ran, this is my code and I am trying to draw the Status from the Holidays table but I do not know how to do with other than passing it though my html connection which wont work for other reasons.

This is my SQL store procedure up to now, if I can get the status to be drawn from the holidays table I can finish it and it will work fine: (I'm quite new to SQL as well so try not to be too complicated THANKS :) )

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHolidayApproveOrDecline]
(
@JobRole INT,
@HolidayID INT,
@Status varchar
)

AS
BEGIN
    SET @Status AS
```

(THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO SET
THE STATUS AS THE VALUE FROM THE HOLIDAYS TABLE!!!!)

```
    IF @JobRole = '1003'
        BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
        IF @Status = 'Pending'
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Holidays     
                SET Status = 'ManagerAcc'
                WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
                AND Status = 'Pending'
            END
        IF @Status = 'AdminAcc'
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Holidays     
                SET Status = 'Accepted'
                WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
                AND Status = 'AdminAcc'
            END
        END

    IF @JobRole = '1002'
        BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
            IF @Status = 'Pending'
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Holidays     
                    SET Status = 'AdminAcc'
                    WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
                    AND Status = 'Pending'
                END
            IF @Status = 'ManagerAcc'
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Holidays     
                    SET Status = 'Accepted'
                    WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
                    AND Status = 'ManagerAcc'
                END
        END
END
```

Comment: Even if you *do* want your `@Status` parameter to have a length of 1, which I doubt in this case, it's usually best to include an explicit length for all `varchar` declarations (just so its obvious to later readers that you wanted a `varchar(1)`). However, in this case, I think it's a mistake and you didn't want its length to be 1, given comparisons such as `@Status = 'ManagerAcc'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your whole procedure can be replaced by a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Holidays     
SET Status = CASE
    WHEN @JobRole = 1003 and Status = 'Pending' THEN 'ManagerAcc'
    WHEN @JobRole = 1003 and Status = 'AdminAcc' THEN 'Accepted'
    WHEN @JobRole = 1002 and Status = 'Pending' THEN 'AdminAcc'
    WHEN @JobRole = 1002 and Status = 'ManagerAcc' THEN 'Accepted'
    ELSE Status END
WHERE @HolidayID = Holidays.ID
```

If you're wanting to have `@Status` available to your callers, the parameter would need to be declared as `OUTPUT` which it currently isn't, so I won't do the extension that actually sets the `@Status` variable since it seems unnecessary.

---

In general, you should find ways in SQL to tell the system *what to do*, not *how to do it*. You shouldn't think, okay, first I'll extract the current status. Then, based on the current status and the job role, I'll apply a specific update. Tell the system what the specific conditions are and let it work out what order to do things in.

---

You should also be very careful whenever you specify a [`varchar(n)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) variable or column, because:

> When *n* is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

You rarely, if ever, actually want a `varchar(1)` variable.

> When *n* is not specified when using the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions, the default length is 30

This is a slightly more useful data type, but is annoying just because there doesn't seem a good reason to have different defaults for `n` in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks very much! worked perfectly and better than my original :)